# Remover objeto de un array PHP

Tags: php, array, codeigniter

```
{
    "success": true,
    "response": [
        {
            "idseparacion": "1",
            "idcalidad": "21",
            "peso": "500",
            "cajas": "50",
            "restante": 100
        },
        {
            "idseparacion": "2",
            "idcalidad": "21",
            "peso": "1000",
            "cajas": "50",
            "restante": 0
            },
    ],
}
```

tengo mi json como se encuentra en el formato el problema es que quiero eliminar los elementos que tengan `restante 0` utilice:

`unset($data[$key]);`

lo cual me elimina los datos bien, el problema es que les agregar entre comillas el numero de objeto quedando así:

```
"response": [
        "1":{ ///<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            "idseparacion": "1",
            "idcalidad": "21",
            "peso": "500",
            "cajas": "50",
            "restante": 100
        }
    ],
```

> ¿Porque esta sucediendo esto?

*Que otra forma me recomiendad para eliminar objetos*

> Código PHP

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
                $cajasSeparacion = $this->getCajasCalidad($value['idseparacion']);
                $cajasTarimadas = $this->getTarimasCajas($value['idseparacion']);
                $valorRestante = $cajasSeparacion->cajas - $cajasTarimadas->tarimadas;
                $data[$key]['restante'] = $valorRestante;
                if($valorRestante <= 0){
                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaría no manipular demasiado los objetos, a no ser que no tengas otra salida.

En este caso puedes tratar tu objeto como un JSON durante todo el recorrido, evitando una conversión a array que realmente no te aporta nada.

Por ejemplo, para hacer lo que dices en la pregunta, con esto bastaría:

```
/*Evitamos TRUE para dejarlo como JSON*/
$data=json_decode($str);

foreach($data->response as $k=>$item){
    if ($item->restante <= 0){
        unset($data->response[$k]);
    }
}
```

Si probamos ahora los datos:

```
var_dump($data);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
      ["idseparacion"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["idcalidad"]=>
      string(2) "21"
      ["peso"]=>
      string(3) "500"
      ["cajas"]=>
      string(2) "50"
      ["restante"]=>
      int(100)
    }
  }
}
```

---

Si por algún motivo lo quieres trabajar como array, *no problem*, lo puedes hacer tranquilamente:

```
/*Pasamos TRUE para convertirlo a array*/
$arr=json_decode($str,TRUE);

foreach ($arr["response"] as $k=>$response){
    if ($response["restante"] <= 0){
    unset($arr["response"][$k]);
    }
}
```

Probamos el array resultante:

```
var_dump($arr);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idseparacion"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["idcalidad"]=>
      string(2) "21"
      ["peso"]=>
      string(3) "500"
      ["cajas"]=>
      string(2) "50"
      ["restante"]=>
      int(100)
    }
  }
}
```